# Trust Relationship Error AssumeRole policy may only specify STS AssumeRole actions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

I am trying to add trust relationships to allow codedeploy to work for my role

I have the following json

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": ["ec2.amazonaws.com", "codedeploy.amazonaws.com"]
      },
      "Action": ["sts:AssumeRole",
                "codedeploy:GetApplication",
                "codedeploy:GetDeploymentGroup",
                "codedeploy:CreateDeployment",
                "codedeploy:GetDeployment"      
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I keep getting the following error

[image]

Comment: have you tried to break down into two statements? one for `sts:AssumeRole` and other for `codedeploy:*` ?

Comment: I tried this with the same error {
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "ec2.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "codedeploy.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "codedeploy:*"
    }
  ]
}

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are mixing two different concepts in the policy: trust relationship and IAM actions.

You need to have two different policies, one for the IAM Role like:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "ec2.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
```

and other for the IAM Policy as:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "codedeploy.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": [
        "codedeploy:GetApplication",
        "codedeploy:GetDeploymentGroup",
        "codedeploy:CreateDeployment",
        "codedeploy:GetDeployment"
     ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I added the seperate policy but i still get the following error in my pipeline This task requires permissions to call the following AWS service APIs (depending on selected task options, not all APIs may be used):
* codedeploy:GetApplication
* codedeploy:GetDeploymentGroup
* codedeploy:CreateDeployment
* codedeploy:GetDeployment

Comment: @MicroMan having a look at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/getting-started-create-service-role.html, it looks like you need to set the principals the other way around. You want to have `sts:AssumeRole` for the codedeploy principal, and `ec2.amazonaws.com` for the codedeploy actions

Comment: Could you send an example, i am not sure what u mean?

Comment: @MicroMan in the example above, change `ec2.amazonaws.com` for `codedeploy.amazonaws.com` in the first policy, and `codedeploy.amazonaws.com` for `ec2.amazonaws.com` in the second one.

Comment: if i do that i get an exception in the second "This policy contains the following error: Has prohibited field Principal For more information about the IAM policy grammar, see AWS IAM Policies"

Comment: @MicroMan remove the Principal section in the second. at all, it's not necessary there. `Principal` is Policies is used for specifying which actors can perform the Actions in which Resources.